# Getting one data from another table in DropownList with AutoPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, drop-down-menu

I have a  Customer table --> `CustomerNumber` and `CustomerName` columns

I have a Sales table --> `CustomerName` columns

I have a `Label` (represent CustomerNumber) and a `DropDownList` (represent CustomerName)

I getting to `DropDownList` Sales table --> CustomerName with `SqlDataSource`.

I want automaticly (with AutoPostBack) filling Label with CustomerNumber which CustomerName selected in DropDownList

Example SQL:

select A.CustomerNumber 
from Customer A, Sales B 
where B.CustomerName = DropDownList1.SelectedItems.Value

I'm thinking like this.

How can i do that?

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: You are in right direction. I see you are getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
 string selectedName = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

 string sqlQuery = "select A.CustomerNumber from Customer A, Sales B where B.CustomerName = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'";
 // pass you sql query to command object and call execute scalar method
 label1.Text = dbCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

}

What do [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(-1 != DropDownList1.SelectedIndex)
{
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
connection.Open();
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT A.CUSTOMERNUMBER FROM CUSTOMER A, SALES B WHERE B.CUSTOMERNAME = @CustomerName"))
{
command.Connection = connection;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", DropDownlist1.SelectedValue.ToString());
this.Label1.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
}
}
}
```

Hope it works. *Disclaimer : I didn't tested the code*